# jQuery and Ajax Form Validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a problem with Jquery form validation.

I have this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var validateUsername = $('.info');
  $('#username').blur(function () {

var t = this; 
if (this.value != this.lastValue) {
  if (this.timer) clearTimeout(this.timer);
  validateUsername.removeClass();
  validateUsername.addClass('info');
  validateUsername.html('<img src="images/load.gif" height="16" width="16" /> checking availability...');

  this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      url: 'process.php',
      data: 'action=validateusername&username=' + t.value,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      success: function (j) {
        validateUsername.removeClass();
        validateUsername.addClass(j.class);
        validateUsername.html(j.msg); 
      }
    });

  }, 500);

  this.lastValue = this.value;
}

  })
});
```

and in php something like this :

```
public static function validateUserName($username) {
    $username = trim($username); // remove white spacing
    $response = array(); // define response array

    if(!$username) { // check if not empty
        $response = array(
            "ok"  => false,
            "class"  => "error",
            "msg" => "Please specify your username");
    } elseif (strlen($username)<5) { // check the lenght
        $response = array(
            "ok"  => false,
            "class"  => "error",
            "msg" => "UserName must be at least 5 characters long");
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+$/',$username)) { // check the pattern
        $response = array(
            "ok"  => false,
            "class"  => "error",
            "msg" => "Your username can contain only Aplhanumerics, dash, underscore and period");
    } elseif (!self::userNameAvailable($username)) { // check availability
        $response = array(
            "ok"  => false,
            "class"  => "error",
            "msg" => "UserName already taken !");
    } else { // everything good
        $response = array(
            "ok"  => true,
            "class"  => "success",
            "msg" => "This username is free");
    }

    return $response;
}
```

As you can see php returns 3 fields of data....
problem is the user can still send the form even when php returns "false" and i have no idea how to fix it.

I could just let the form to be sent a do one more validating purely with php, 
but what is the point of using ajax then.

I´d be very thankful if somebody could help me.

Comment: use the value of `j.ok` to determine what should happen in the `success` callback. You receive it, but dont do anything with it.

Comment: find out what your success function is returning in AJAX: inside `function() {}` put `console.log(j);` and find out what's coming back (which is what you'll check for). if it's JSON data, it might be `j.responseText` you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple solution is to set a global variable:

```
var validform = false;
```

And check it in form submit event :

```
$("#myform").submit(function(){
    return validform;
});
```

Now you can set it as TRUE or FALSE on your AJAX callback.

```
$.ajax({
  // Whatever',
    success: function (j) {
      validform = true;
    }
});
```

you can do a little more customization too.

Comment: thanks man, i tried to do something similar, but it did't work ! now it seems to be working, im sure i´ve made some silly mistake...
thanks again... ;)

Comment: sorry to bother you again but i tried to simplify my code
`function validateName(){
  var valid = false;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'process.php',
          data: 'action=validateusername&username=' + name.val(),
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'post',
          success: function (j) {
            nameInfo.removeClass();
            nameInfo.addClass(j.class);
            nameInfo.text(j.msg);
            valid = j.ok;
           }       
        });
      return valid;
}`

and again it works just fine but the variable "valid" is never changing to "true".

Comment: @user2847975 you are using `json` as dataType in your ajax request. The success event will fired just if the result is a valid JSON object. Please make sure if this event is firing or not. If not, make sure your server side script is sending a valid JSON object to output.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you validate every 500ms and not on form submit or input change?

General pattern for form validation using jQuery is to validate on form's `submit()` event, like:

```
$('form').submit(function () { 
    ...
    (validation code here)
    ...
});
```

If validation doesn't succeed, you can just return false from `submit()` to avoid submitting the form.

Also note that you **need to do server-side validation of posted data, too**, as jQuery validation can be fooled easily.